# How to show background image once?

Tags: html, css, background-image, photoshop

How can I prevent my background from displaying multiple times?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```
.your-target-class {
  background-image: url('your_url');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use no-repeat..

```css
.yourClass{
  background:url("./path/yourIMG") no-repeat;
}
```

}